# A command line for registry comparison tool

Tags: python, registry

I was looking for a command line api for a tool of comparing registry keys before and after some operations I was doing.

I've found a tool for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/regshot/) , however I don't see any option to operate this tool via a command line interface, only through GUI.
Does anybody know if this tool has a command line api option, or know some other tools for allowing me comparing registry state via a command line api?

Answer (score 0):

You can first query the registry to get the two results in plain text format. You would then compare the results with any suitable tool.

Options for querying:

1. The `reg` command

   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx

   http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html
2. The `regedit` command [may also be useful](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/168589).
3. Powershell´s `Get-ItemProperty`

   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176852.aspx

   http://ss64.com/ps/get-itemproperty.html